# How to change calculation on nv3d when switching to stacked?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using d3.js and nvd3.js to display some data from different datasets. One of the sets (A) contains the absolute number of orders, the other set (B) contains the number of orders from new customers, such that A >= B for every position. Example:

```
[{
  key   : 'orders',
  values: [[1, 10], [2, 5], [3, 8], ...]
},{
  key   : 'orders by new customers',
  values: [[1, 4],  [2, 0], [3, 4], ...]
}]
```

I'd like to use a stacked multibar chart to display those series. In "Grouped" view, everything works nicely and I have both bars grouped beneath each other. However, when I switch to "Stacked" mode I was expecting, that the overall number does not change. It appeared that nv3d.js is then adding up both values and i get a new overall value.

Is there a way to change the calculation when switching to stacked mode? I was digging through the source code, but could not find a usable method to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct that you would have to modify the source code to do this -- however, it's much easier to simply modify your data, either when generating the JSON or in Javascript before passing it to NVD3.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, it would make more sense to restructure your data to make it conceptually match with bars being 'stacked' (which implies two values being added together), to something like this where:

orders = recurring orders + orders by new customers

```
[{
  key   : 'recurring orders',
  values: [[0, 6], [0, 5], [0, 4], ...]
},{
  key   : 'orders by new customers',
  values: [[1, 4],  [2, 0], [3, 4], ...]
}]
```

Comment: I understand that my data should match the concepts of the chart used to display those. However I thought that nvd3 would be a little more flexible here. Do you know, if there's some kind of callback that is being triggered, when switching from grouped to stacked, such that I can change my data values on demand?

Comment: Understood. If you search for Stacked in multiBar.js (in src/models in github repo) you can see how stacked bars are handled and it seems that unfortunately you cannot pass your own stack-handler, but you can modify the code and create your own version.